# Finding quartile of normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, quantile

Find the quartiles :$Q_{1},Q_{2},Q_{3}$ of  $X \in N(2,9)$

What I have tried :
So for $Q_{1}$ for example , $Q_{1}  =\frac{1}{4}$

$ X ~ (\mu,k^2) = P(X \le x)= P(kx+\mu \le x) = P(Z \le \frac{x-\mu}{k})=Φ (\frac{x-\mu}{k})$ in our case it will be $Φ (\frac{1/4-2}{3}) =Φ (-0.58)$.Then
I should look at the normal distribution table for the answer and that is it ?

Comment: The quartile is **not** where x= 1/4 but where $N(x;\mu, k^2)= 1/4$.  You need to use a table of the normal distribution to find x such that $\Phi\left(\frac{x-2}{9}\right)= 0.25$.  And then, of course, "= 0.50" and "= 0.75".

Comment: The first quartile, say, is at the $x$ where $\Phi \left ( \frac{x-\mu}{k} \right )=1/4$. The second (which is to say the median) is where it is equal to $1/2$, etc.

Comment: @user247327 Shouldn't it be divided by 3? then  $Φ (\frac{2-x}{3}) =0.75$ and I got from the table the result 0.69 for 0.75.Then $\frac{2-x}{3}$ = 0.69 and we find x.Is that approach correct?

Comment: @Joel It would be $\frac{x-2}{3}$ in this situation, not $\frac{2-x}{3}$. But yes, if $9$ is the variance and not the standard deviation then you divide by $3$ not $9$.